# form input date picker not showing on ajax page

Tags: jquery, laravel

I've been trying to use the jquery datepicker on my ajax page but it fails to load.Am developing a web app on laravel framework and ajax but when i try to use the jquery datepicker it only works if the form is on my master page.but once i click on a link which loads a new page into a div the datepicker doesnt work there.And my console isnt throwing any errors.Any idea what i might bee doing wrong.

Here is the example on jquery website that i followed.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my ajax call

```
function makerequest(serverPage, objID) {
var obj = document.getElementById(objID);
obj.innerHTML = '<b>Loading....</b>';
xmlhttp.open("GET", serverPage);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
obj.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

page am trying to load into div

```
     <form method="POST" action="{{URL::route('applicant.store')}}" class="user form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker">
        <h4 class="text-center">ENROLLEE REGISTRATION FORM</h4>
    <!--div to contain ajax passport-->
       <!-- <div id="passport" class="text-center" style="border:1px solid black;height:120px;width:120px;color:silver"></div> -->

       <!--surname and othernames-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-offset-">        
            <label for="name">Surname</label>        
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" name="surname" required value="{{Input::old('surname')}}" class="form-control">

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-offset-">        
            <label for="name">Other Names</label>        
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" name="othernames" required value="{{Input::old('othernames')}}" class="form-control">

            </div>
        </div>

          <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-">        
            <label for="name">Upload Passport</label>        
            </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
       <input type="file" name="passport" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-"> 
        <div>       
            <label for="form_no">Form NO.</label>        
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
            <input type="text" name="form_no" value="{{Input::old('form_no')}}" class="form-control" required>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-">        
            <label for="tell_no">Teller/Reciept NO.</label>        
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" name="tell_no" value="{{Input::old('tell_no')}}" class="form-control" required>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-offset-">        
            <label for="amt_paid">Amount Paid</label>        
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
            <input type="text" name="amt_paid" value="{{Input::old('amt_paid')}}" class="form-control" required>
            </div>

     </div>   

         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-offset-">                                 
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;Submit Application Form</button>

        </div>
</form>
        </div>

    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
        </div>

<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
$( "#regpicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: you need to initiate the plugin after teh ajax content is loaded

Comment: you need to write $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(); in ajax success section.

Comment: by this do you mean under my onreadystatechange function? dont get u clearly

Answer (score 0):

Put all of your script references in master page which are common throughout the application.So all plugins would be initiated when master page loads so you will not have to add references in your child pages and will not have to worry about plugins.

Comment: that exactly what i did

Comment: OK post your code in which you are loading page by ajax.

Comment: Move script section in datepicker page at end after body tag.

Answer (score 0):

My answer was related with the DOM for assigning the events/widget to the DOM element while serving the AJAX request

Try to attach the datepicker on **pageload** event as follows

```
$("document").on("pageload",function(event,data){
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
}) ;
```

or you can just use the following implementation

```
function pageload()
{
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
}
```

hope it helps...

Comment: please check the following code `$(function(){ alert($( "#datepicker" ).length) });` does it returns value greater than **0** ?

Comment: it alerts a value of 0

Answer (score 0):

Remove the jQuery reference in the new page which you are loading in to the div. 
If you are using the jQuery reference in both your master page and the new page it may cause a multiple reference which may cause this type of problem.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

So try using the jQuery references in you master page alone.

Comment: i did not add this refrences to the div am loading.are you saying i should include all the script into the div except the jquery refrences

Comment: <script>
$('document').ready(function(){
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
$( "#regpicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>

Comment: added just that alone to the bottom of my div.but still doesnt work

Comment: No,You don't  need to add any reference in you div
I asked you to remove the references in your another page which you are loading to the div

Comment: Can you post the code of your page which you are trying to load into the div?

Comment: The page seems to be fine